# Why isn't my class inheriting a method defined in its base class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm working through Data Structures and Algorithms by Goodrich et al, and I'm having trouble understanding why the below code is having an error.  Specifically, this is an implementation of an unsorted priority queue.  The below code contains four classes: a base class for a doubly linked positional list, a positional list, a base class for a priority queue, and an unsorted priority queue.  At the end of class definitions I create an unsorted priority queue, add three key/values to it, and then try to find the minimum.  However, an error occurs that says that "UnsortedPriorityQueue has no attribute 'is_empty'" when the method "_find_min" is called.  But why isn't "is_empty" being inherited from its base class?

```
class _DoublyLinkedBase:
    
    class _Node:
        __slots__ = '_element', '_prev', '_next'

        def __init__(self, _element, _prev, _next):
            self._element = _element
            self._prev = _prev
            self._next = _next

    def __init__(self):
        self._header = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self._trailer = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self._header._next = self._trailer
        self._trailer._prev = self._header
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def _insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        newest = self._Node(e, predecessor, successor)
        predecessor._next = newest
        successor._prev = newest
        self._size += 1
        return newest

    def _delete_node(self, node):
        predecessor = node._prev
        successor = node._next
        predecessor._next = successor
        successor._prev = predecessor
        self._size -= 1
        element = node._element
        node._prev = node._next = node._element = None #Depreciate node
        return element
        
        
        
        
class PositionalList(_DoublyLinkedBase):

    class Position:

        def __init__(self, container, node):
            self._container = container
            self._node = node

        def element(self):
            return self._node._element

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return type(other) is type(self) and other._node is self._node

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not(self == other)

    def _validate(self, p):
        if not isinstance(p, self.Position):
            raise TypeError( 'p must be proper Position type' )
        if p._container is not self:
            raise ValueError( 'p does not belong to this container' )
        if p._node._next is None: # convention for deprecated nodes
            raise ValueError( 'p is no longer valid' )
        return p._node

    def _make_position(self, node):
        if node is self._header or node is self._trailer:
            return None
        else:
            return self.Position(self, node)

    def first(self):
        return self._make_position(self._header._next)

    def last(self):
        return self._make_position(self._trailer._prev)

    def before(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._prev)

    def after(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._next)

    def __iter__(self):
        cursor = self.first()
        while cursor is not None:
            yield cursor.element()
            cursor = self.after(cursor)

    def _insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        node = super()._insert_between(e, predecessor, successor)
        return self._make_position(node)

    def add_first(self, e):
        return self._insert_between(e, self._header, self._header._next)

    def add_last(self, e):
        return self._insert_between(e, self._trailer._prev, self._trailer)

    def add_before(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, original._prev, original)

    def add_after(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, original, original._next)

    def delete(self, p):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._delete_node(orignal)

    def replace(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        old_value = original._element
        original._element = e
        return old_value
        
class PriorityQueueBase:
    class _Item:
        __slots__ = '_key', '_value'
        def __init__(self, k, v):
            self._key = k
            self._value = v
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self._key < other._key #Compare items based on keys
        def is_empty(self):
            return len(self) == 0
        
class UnsortedPriorityQueue(PriorityQueueBase):
    #_data is a positional list
    def _find_min(self): #Nonpublic utility, means it shouldn't be accessed->
        if self.is_empty():                           #-> outside of the class
            raise Exception('Priority Queue is empty.')
        small = self._data.first() #This is a positional list
        walk = self._data.after(small)
        while walk is not None:
            if walk.element() < small.element():
                small = walk
            walk = self._data.after(walk)
        return small
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = PositionalList()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
    def add(self, key, value):
        #PositionalList elements are _Items.
        self._data.add_last(self._Item(key, value))
    def min(self):
        p = self._find_min()
        item = p.element()
        #PositionalList elements are _Items.
        return (item._key, item._value)
    def remove_min(self):
        p = self._find_min()
        item = self._data.delete(p)
q = UnsortedPriorityQueue()
q.add(1, 'a')
q.add(2, 'b')
q.add(3, 'c')
q.min()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm just trying to understand the data structures in the book and this is how the code is presented.  Is there something in particular about the use of the inner classes here?

Comment: Because the base class doesn't implement `is_empty`. Your base class `PriorityQueueBase ` has a single attribute, `_Item`. You know, nesting classes like this isn't generally a pattern you see in Python. You can make it work, but it is unidiomatic. NOTE: your code contains *seven* classes, not four. In any case, this just seems to be unintentional indentation.

Comment: I was reading your code differently and didn't understand what you were attempting to achieve. Seems you made an indentation error which confused me. No harm

Comment: @OliverG also, as an aside, **please always provide a [mcve]**. The vast majority of this code could have been removed to reproduce the error, and indeed, you probably would have found this error if you has tried to create the [mcve] yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it's not defined for that class. `is_empty` is defined for the inner class `_Item`, not the `PriorityQueueBase`.

Edit: I took another stab at your code and I think it's just an indentation issue. The problem should be solved if you properly de-indent the `is_empty` method.